# Find if AWS instance is running Amazon Linux 1 or 2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

In AWS I need to add amazon linux instance to domain based on this [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/join_linux_instance.html).
However how do i know which Amazon Linux version the instance is using.
I do not have access to AWS console. But i do have access to actual instance.
What linux command i should be using.

I use `uname -srm` command which returns `Linux 4.4.0-1057-aws x86_64`

Not sure if this is Amazon Linux 1 or Amazon Linux 2

Answer (score 79):

You can use `/etc/os-release` file to get the info about Amazon Linux Version, the machine is running.

1. In case of **Amazon 1**

   ```
   [ec2-user@ip-x-x-x- ~]$ cat /etc/os-release
   NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
   VERSION="2018.03"
   ID="amzn"
   ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
   VERSION_ID="2018.03"
   PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
   ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
   CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
   HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
   ```
2. In case of **Amazon 2**

   ```
   [ec2-user@x-x-x-x ~]$ cat /etc/system-release
   Amazon Linux release 2.0 (2017.12) LTS Release Candidate
   [ec2-user@fresh-amazon-host ~]$ cat /etc/os-release
   NAME="Amazon Linux"
   VERSION="2.0 (2017.12)"
   ID="amzn"
   ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
   VERSION_ID="2.0"
   PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2.0 (2017.12) LTS Release Candidate"
   ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
   CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2.0"
   HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
   ```

As you can clearly see the two different versions, mentioned as Amazon Linux and Amazon Linux 2.0

Comment: what is the excet meaning ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora", Is this support all three distros

Comment: The format of the various environment variables seems to have changed a bit, but these files are indeed present.

Comment: cat /etc/os-release

Answer (score 13):

```
$ cat /etc/system-release
```

or

```
$ cat /etc/issue
```

or

```
$ uname -a
```

and head for https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/

Answer (score 4):

Here's a one-liner.

```sh
awk -F '[="]*' '/^PRETTY_NAME/ { print $2 }' < /etc/os-release
```

It prints out:

```
Amazon Linux 2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following command:

```
rpm -E %{rhel}
```

For Operating System: Amazon Linux 2

**`The answer is : 7`**

Comment: without the asterisks logically :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, the announcement in: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/12/introducing-amazon-linux-2 states that it uses a 4.9 kernel. Yours is older, so I would say it is Linux 1.

Still, the following call from the terminal should give you the AMI ID and you could do a search on that(see docs at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html):

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ami-id
```

Comment: Just know that the AMI ID may not tell you anything.  If the instance was created off of a custom AMI then it may not even exist anymore.